# how to refer two data frames from one reactive function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have following reactive function in `server.r`

```
 test <- reactive({ 

 test_1
 test_2

})

output$table1 <- renderTable({

 test_1
})

output$table2 <- renderTable({

 test_2
})
```

I want to refer `test_1 & test_2` from one reactive function to two different output tables.

How can I achieve above ?

Answer (score 2):

Correct way of referring multiple dataframes is as follows

```
test <- reactive({ 
  test_1
  test_2
  list(df1 = test_1, df2 = test_2)

})

output$table1 <- renderTable({
   test()[['df1']]
})
output$table2 <- renderTable({
   test()[['df2']]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one function, but return:

```
list(df1=test_1, df2=test_2)
```

Then refer to these in your your other functions

```
test()$df1
test()$df2
```

Don't forget the parenthesis before the $

Answer (score -2):

Try putting reactive data frames into a list:

```
test <- reactive({ 
  test_1
  test_2
  testData <- list(test_1, test_2)
  testData ## added this
})

output$table1 <- renderTable({
  testData <- test()
  testData$test_1
})
output$table2 <- renderTable({
  testData <- test()      
  testData$test_2
})
```

An expanded version of this works for me in a 'renderLeaflet` application.

Comment: I just added a needed line to the reactive function to specify that testData is returned.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I am still getting the same error `testData not found`

Comment: Correct, as you got to above.  I was not working with an actual MWE, Glad the 'put it in a list' approach worked for you.